# Adding max_input_vars 3000 to my .htaccess file and php.ini not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've done some searching and seems everything I've read and tried with adding `max_input_vars 3000` to my .htaccess and php.ini is not working. I've reached the limit on custom fields and can't get the max increased. I added these lines and restarted apache but nothing helps.

Here is what I added to .htaccess:

```
php_value max_input_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.get.max_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 3000
```

And here is my php.ini:

```
max_input_vars 3000
suhosin.get.max_vars 3000
suhosin.post.max_vars 3000
suhosin.request.max_vars 3000
```

Comment: Does `phpinfo();` mention any other ini files loaded? Is there a `php_admin_value`  in your webserver config somewhere?

Comment: What value do you see in output of `phpinfo();`?

Comment: My output of `phpinfo()` states that this is the config file `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/conf`

Comment: @tjoenz what values of the parameters you are changing do you see in output of `phpinfo()`?

Comment: @Cheery I see that Local Value shows my `max_input_vars`is 3000 and Master Value is 1000

Comment: @tjoenz so, if you php script is running in the folder which has local value, then this is a value you set up. If it does not help, the problem might be in another place. And you did not describe it - do you have submitted data cut or server shows some error..

Comment: @Cheery I looked in the logs and it said that 3000 still was not enough. I bumped it to 5000 and it works. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Repost from:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/29312220/3827361][1]

I had the same issue, and I fixed it by setting max_input_vars value in this php.ini: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

even though php_info() reported a different php.ini used (/etc/php5/cli/php.ini). BTW, before I stumbled upon the solution, I also tried setting up the value in .htaccess (in the web page root directory), with no effect.

This looks like a possible bug in PHP 5.5. In any case, I suggest locating all php.ini files on your server ("locate php.ini") and setting max_input_vars in all of them (or the first one that works, eh). Don't forget to restart Apache so this takes effect (sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart)

BTW, my PHP Version is 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5, installed on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your **max_input_vars** value to 2000 or any value that you want in htaccess by adding this for PHP 7.*:

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    php_value max_input_vars 2000
</IfModule>
```

And for PHP 8.* use this:

```
<IfModule mod_php8.c>
    php_value max_input_vars 2000
</IfModule>
```